# Fourier transform of an exponential function with radical argument divided by a radical

Tags: integration, special-functions, fourier-transform, integral-transforms, bessel-functions

I have $f(t)=\dfrac{e^{-i\sqrt{(t-t_0)^2+A^2}}}{\sqrt{(t-t_0)^2+A^2}}$ where $t_0$ and $A$ are constant. I need to take the Fourier transform of $f(t)$. I made few substitutions to take it to a form where I can look it up in a table but to no avail. Thanks.

Comment: this Fourier transform is not likely to have a closed-form expression; even the exponent by itself has no closed-form Fourier transform

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker I have the answer $\frac{i}{2} H_0^{(1)}(\sqrt{1-\omega^2} \sqrt{A^2})$. In my problem, I have $A^2=R^2+B^2-2R.B.cos(\theta)$. $R$, $B$, and $\theta$ do not depend on $t$. The Fourier transform is taken with $\frac{1}{2 \pi}$. So it is a Hankel function but do not come up with the answer yet.